# Is it possible to create a smart contract from a multi sig smart contract wallet?

Tags: erc-20, multisignature, wallet-contracts

Is it possible to create a smart contract, for example a ERC-20 from a multi signature smart contract wallet?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible - but very interested in your use-case

Comment: Want to make sure 4-7 people approve when minting new tokens.

Comment: You could/should write a smart-contract to do so

Comment: So your saying instead of having the multi-sig wallet create the smart contract just have the multi sig part in the minting function?

Comment: Yes - this is how I would do it and I think it is the way to go.

Comment: A common solution is to create the contract from a normal account, and later change ownershipt to the multisig wallet. So `onlyOwner` functions needs approval from the majority of the multisig owners.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is possible, but wallet contract has to support this.  Normal transactions and smart contract creations are performed via different opcodes, and most implementations of multisig wallets just do not have opcodes for smart contracts creation, namely `CREATE` and `CREATE2`.  [ABDK Multisig Wallet](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-multisig-wallet/) is an example of multisig wallet with contract creation ability.